# Stack: random dependency cycle(s) detected

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

The contents of `stack.yaml` is as follows:

```yaml
resolver: lts-16.19

packages:
  - .

extra-deps:
  - text-1.2.4.0
  - random-1.2.0
  - git: https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv.git # sbv
    commit: 4f4baa7b5970ef2ab9b322c6694bf9df6ccdbc4b
  - git: https://github.com/bos/aeson # aeson
    commit: 8579faf30e0f977425fbf330038fb1d5c2c34727
  - data-fix-0.3.0@sha256:058a266d1e658500e0ffb8babe68195b0ce06a081dcfc3814afc784b083fd9a5,1645
  - strict-0.4@sha256:1b50c7c9c636c3a1bbc7f8873b9be48f6ca0faca4df6eec6a014de6208fb1c0e,4200
```

While `test` has this section:

```yaml
executable test
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       text, random, sbv, aeson, base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

I added `text` and `random` because if I don't, I get the following errors when running `stack ghci`:

```sh
Could not load module ‘Data.Text’
Could not load module ‘System.Random’
```

But now, with these packages added as they are above, Stack complains about circular dependencies:

```sh
$ stack setup
$ stack ghci

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for QuickCheck-2.13.2:
    random dependency cycle detected: random, splitmix, random, uuid-types, aeson, test
needed due to test-0.1.0.0 -> QuickCheck-2.13.2

In the dependencies for test-0.1.0.0:
    random dependency cycle detected: random, splitmix, random, uuid-types, aeson, test
needed since test is a build target.

Dependency cycle detected in packages:
    [random,splitmix,random,uuid-types,aeson,test]

In the dependencies for sbv-8.8.5:
    random dependency cycle detected: random, splitmix, random, uuid-types, aeson, test
needed due to test-0.1.0.0 -> sbv-8.8.5

In the dependencies for splitmix-0.0.5:
    random dependency cycle detected: random, splitmix, random, uuid-types, aeson, test
needed due to test-0.1.0.0 -> splitmix-0.0.5

Some different approaches to resolving this:


Error: Plan construction failed.
```

Based on the error messages it looks that there's a circular between `splitmix`, and `random`. I only asked for `random` therefore I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Any way to fix this and make the imports work while avoiding this circular imports issue would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the whole cabal file?

Answer (score 4):

The newest `random` is not compatible with the old version of `splitmix` in the `lts-16.19` snapshot. Add a newer version of `splitmix` in `extra-deps`:

```
extra-deps:
- ...  # your other extra-deps
- splitmix-0.1.0.3
```